# Value error with confusion matrix of sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I made a code to apply to several folders to make random forests. It seems to work on the first two and hangs on the third on my confusion matrix telling me that there is only 1 value in my matrix instead of the usual 4. I do not see where the error is and why it is done on the third file t not on the first two.

here is my code :

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_path) 
X = df.iloc[:, 4:]
y = df.iloc[:, 3]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1) 
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=69) model.fit(X_train, y_train) y_pred = model.predict(X_test)  

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) 
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5) 
balanced_acc = balanced_accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)  

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) 
tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel() 
sensi = tp / (tp + fn) 
speci = tn / (tn + fp)
```

and here is my output with error

```
fichier Dossier_1
charge dataframe
entrainement du model
prédiction sur model
Précision : 83.33%
Dossier_1
[0.75       0.75       0.75       0.66666667 1.        ]
fichier autres
fichier Dossier_68
charge dataframe
entrainement du model
prédiction sur model
Précision : 72.09%
Dossier_68
[0.65384615 0.65384615 0.76923077 0.69230769 0.52      ]
fichier Dossier_69
charge dataframe
entrainement du model
prédiction sur model
Précision : 100.00%
Dossier_69
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cours\Master 1 ISDD\Stage\scikit_learn.py", line 66, in <module>
    tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

I tried to do it manually on this folder and by displaying cm I see that there is only 1 element in cm but I don't know what I can do to fix it